# Joomla custom component customizations

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I needed a component for specific catalog, so I've paid for it to one freelancer. As it turned out, he's not very good at his job and I was given a component that works only partly. The biggest issues are router, breadcrumbs and json array for parent categories.

### 1. Router

currently it shows only domain.com/menuitem/viewname?id=X. There are 4 different views that looks like are not connected at all. in db, every view has its own table as it was requested, important fields are as follows:

```
Main Categories (root):
id, name, alias

General Categories:
id, name, alias, root_id

General Subcategories:
id, name, alias, cat_id

Detail:
id, name, alias, subcat_id[json array]
```

What I would like to do is to make SEF urls to look like this: domain.com/menuitem/root_alias/category_alias/subcategory_alias/detail_alias but I was told that it can't be done this way. I checked the SEF documentation on joomla portal but I can't figure it out (if it's even possible and if not, what would be a good SEO approach).

### 2. Breadcrumbs

Maybe it's caused by router and separate views, but they always show Home > Menuitem, but in mainmenu it's only /alias while in breadcrumbs it's /alias/mainview. I found how to add custom breadcrumbs into pathway on joomla portal, but I can't figure out how to get parent items. If there was a solution with SQL I could use it would be enough.

### <del>3. JSON array in db</del>

<del>I would like to change it to integer value and add new table subcategory_detail_xref so I can find items easily. Only way I can do it now is by using regular expression in SQL which I don't think is a good idea. I've checked tutorials on joomla portal but it looks just too complicated.</del>

Any ideas, links to examples or tutorials that can help or solutions are highly appreciated.

PS: My website is running on latest Joomla (3.5) so if there are solutions only available for 3.5+ it's fine, I don't have any plans to downgrade

Answer (score 0):

For router source code, you can refer to com_content, it's similar yours, in the 3.5 version, the router has to implement an interface.

There is no detail document at Joomla Developer site, com_content is exactly what you can learn to get it.

The breadcrumb you have to develop similar of router logic

Category table should extend the JNestedTable for multiple level tree structure

Comment: I couldn't figure out anything from com_content, but somehow I managed to create a router that works like I need. But now I have problem with homepage, that shows View not found error - it's because of my router is not adding view into segments (but I don't want it there). I used JComponentRouterBase only as I couldn't figure out the interface stuff. Regarding 3rd point, I left it as it is, terrible selects, but it works..